# PHP Loop not working in creating dynamic HTML Tables

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table

I am creating a student fee management form.
My fee_inventory table includes fields id, fee_name, amount, fee_type, class, session

fee_type field can be monthly, quarterly, halfyearly, annually

Now I want to display a table where for each fee_name there will be 12 months

If fee_type='quarterly' rowspan='3'
If fee_type='halfyearly' rowspan='6'
and for annually rowspan will be 12

my php code is given below which is printing an abnormal table.
Once it gets rowspan=3 it should not print the particular  for the next two values of $i.

Help me in getting it correct

```
<?php
    echo '<table border="2"><tr>';

    while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4))
    {
      echo '<td>'.$row4[1].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $data = array();

    while( $row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5) )
    $data[] = $row5;

    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ( $data as $row5 ) 
        {

          if($row5[3]=='monthly')
          echo '<td>'.$row5[3].'</td>';
          else if($row5[3]=='quarterly')
          echo '<td rowspan="3">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
          else if($row5[3]=='halfyearly')
          echo '<td rowspan="6">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
          else if( $row5[3]=='anually')
          echo '<td rowspan="12">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
     }
     echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: What does the `for` loop have to do in this instance? It seems that you're just iterating the `$data` 12 more times than it should be...?

Comment: can u please clarify what do u mean by "Once it gets rowspan=3 it should not print the particular for the next two values of $i."

Comment: for loop is for 12 months...

Comment: if $row[3]=='quarterly' it prints a cell with rowspan=3. So for the loop that is running 12 times i just need this cell to print from loop variable value=1,4,7,10. This is the logic where I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do this

```
<?php
    echo '<table border="2"><tr>';

    while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4))
    {
      echo '<td>'.$row4[1].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $data = array();

    while( $row5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5) )
    $data[] = $row5;
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ( $data as $row5 ) 
    {
        if($row5[3]=='monthly') {
            echo '<td>'.$row5[3].'</td>';
            for($i=1;$i<=11;$i++)
            {
                echo '<td></td>';
            }
        }
        else if($row5[3]=='quarterly')
        {
            echo '<td rowspan="3">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
            for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
            {
                echo '<td rowspan="3"></td>';
            }
        }
        else if($row5[3]=='halfyearly')
        {
            echo '<td rowspan="6">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
            for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
            {
                echo '<td rowspan="6"></td>';
            }
        }
        else if( $row5[3]=='anually')
        {
            echo '<td rowspan="12">'.$row5[3].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: Can u show me the screen shot of what is the outcome of it